# Scrolling not possible on own Website

Tags: html, css

At the moment, I have the following settings in my CSS-Stylesheet:

```
.Body {
background-color: #303030;
background-image: url("Background.png");
background-attachment: scroll;
background-size: cover;
display: block;
background-position: top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body class="Body">
<div>
<img class="Header" src="Header.png">
</div>
</body>
```

I made these settings to assure that the background is responsive which perfectly works right now. 
But I have the problem that I can't scroll down the page which means that no scrollbar is shown.
Otherwise, when I set the width of the image to 100% and my height to 6572px, everything works perfectly
BTW: My image resolution is 1920 x 6572.

PS: I must apologize for my weird English, but it isn't my native language

Comment: That's one tall display.

Comment: There is no ';' after 'background-size : cover'. Does the browser set that property well? And the next?

Comment: is '#Body' the id of 'body' '<body id='Body'>'? If not the the #Body to body

Comment: Just forgot that, it is contained in the original file.

Edit: @Sergeon Yep, I changed .Body and inserted the "class" attribute to the "body-tag" in my HTML file, it doesn't matter

Comment: Please share the project link or try to reproduce it at jsFiddle

Comment: *I can't scroll down the page to see the background.* - Is it that when you try to scroll nothing happens or is it that you can scroll but don't see the background when you do? This line implies that it is the first but the title implies it's the second.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* Your question must also include enough code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I created a pastebin for the style.css at http://pastebin.com/LgW1aXtU
Also, I created a pastebin for the index.html at http://pastebin.com/5fu5wZnL

Comment: A JSFiddle would be much more helpful.

Comment: @TheGenieOfTruth So you mean this thing? https://jsfiddle.net/Lckj8m5q/2/
Sry, but it is my first time that I work with debugging tools like this. :)
Also I updated the upper post with more code. And yes, I mean that nothing happens if I try to scroll down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** UPDATED

Try adding a

`<img class='im' src='Background.png'>`

right after body tag with 
css:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.im{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
    z-index:-1;
    ...
}
```

** UPDATED 2

Here you have a working example: https://codepen.io/jjyepez/pen/AXNorQ